# is there a method of improving raster tile loading?

Tags: openlayers

Raster tile loading seems to work like this:

```
* erase old tile layer image
* fetch new tile layer image   // <-- the tile area is blank during this
* draw new tile layer image
```

The tiles seem to 'blink'; that is, the old tile image is removed, that screen area only shows the background, and then the new tile shows up.

I currently use this in the TileLayer():

```
const src = new XYZ({
   url: 'https://my_titiler_server.com/cog/tile/{z}/{x}/{y}?url=time_01.png';
  }),
```

and later the url is updated via:

```
  src.setUrl('https://my_titiler_server.com/cog/tile/{z}/{x}/{y}?url=time_02.png')
```

Q: are there parameters to the TileLayer mechanism that would make this appear smoothly?

Q: can the WebGL FrameBuffer be used somehow to double buffer the new tiles during loading and then swapped out?

Q: can the WebGL 'filter' expression be used somehow?  I've used 'filter' expressions for WebGL points and lines, and that works great.  I tried making polygons of the raster data, but the number of vertices overwhelms the browser.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be due to the way WebGL tile layers cache tile textures and clear that cache if the url or a parameter is changed.

For example, change `ol/layer/Tile` to `ol/layer/WebGLTile` in https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/wms-time.html and you will see the same problem as you describe.

A workaround in that case is to add a new layer instead of updating the source, and remove the old layer when the new one has loaded by replacing

```
  layers[1].getSource().updateParams({'TIME': startDate.toISOString()});
```

with

```
  const oldLayer = map.getLayers().item(1);
  map.addLayer(
    new TileLayer({
      extent: extent,
      source: new TileWMS({
        attributions: ['Iowa State University'],
        url: 'https://mesonet.agron.iastate.edu/cgi-bin/wms/nexrad/n0r-t.cgi',
        params: {
          'LAYERS': 'nexrad-n0r-wmst',
          'TIME': startDate.toISOString(),
        },
      }),
    }),
  );
  map.once('loadend', () => map.removeLayer(oldLayer));
```